# Return single result based on criteria from two rows in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm working on a project management database, and I need to return the milestone dates but flagged if the primary task is scheduled.  My table looks like this:

```
+-------------+-----------+-----------+-------------+------------+
|    Task     | Milestone | End Date  |   Status    | Constraint |
+-------------+-----------+-----------+-------------+------------+
| Programming | No        | 8/11/2018 | Not Started | Calculated |
| Database    | Yes       | 8/22/2018 | In Process  | Calculated |
| Discovery   | Yes       | 8/1/2018  | In Process  | Calculated |
| Kick Off    | No        | 7/31/2018 | In Process  | Scheduled  |
+-------------+-----------+-----------+-------------+------------+
```

I need the results to be like this

```
+-----------+------------+
|   Phase   |  End Date  |
+-----------+------------+
| Database  | 8/22/2018  |
| Discovery | 7/31/2018* |
+-----------+------------+
```

There are no linkages between the milestone task and the primary task, so I have to pull them up by name.  I've gotten as far as this, but I'm getting an invalid expression error:

```
CASE
 WHEN {title}='Discovery : Discovery Complete' AND {status}='Completed'          
  THEN 'Done'
 WHEN ({title}='Discovery : Discovery Complete' AND {status}<>'Completed')
  AND ({title}='Discovery Meeting' AND {constrainttype} = 'Fixed Start')         
  THEN TO_CHAR({enddate}, 'MM/DD/YYYY') || '*'
 WHEN {title}='Discovery : Discovery Complete' AND {status}<>'Completed'         
  THEN TO_CHAR({enddate}, 'MM/DD/YYYY') 
 ELSE NULL 
END
```

Thanks!!

Comment: What's the specific database?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Comment: I'm actually pulling reports from NetSuite database using a custom ODBC.  The queries are Oracle SQL.

Comment: Oracle? Remove **all** parenthesis from code you posted. As of the way of getting to "target" from "source", no idea - I don't understand what you are saying and can't "join" sample data you posted with words you used to explain the problem. Sorry.